# What the different between TAG_DISCOVERED, NDEF_DISCOVERED and TECH_DISCOVERED in android NFC

Tags: java, android, nfc

i need to know the different between TAG_DISCOVERED, NDEF_DISCOVERED and TECH_DISCOVERED in android NFC (Specifically for Java programming language). Currently i'm trying to use NDEF_DISCOVERED for my app, but it won't detect my e-money card, but if i use TAG_DISCOVERED it can detect the card (the ID). I already read the official documentation but i still not quite understand it. Can someone explain it to me more about this?

Answer (score 0):

The Android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/nfc/nfc#dispatching) outlines the differences

Ndef is a standard data format that is capable to be stored on top of various types of Tag

The Tech types are low level communication specifications and you should be looking for one or more of these. You should use these to communicate to the Tag using commands support by which ever Tag Type you receive, there are some standard commands and various protocols used. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication#Standards) has a nice diagram of these standards an how they fit together.

The [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/package-summary) gives you how to use easy Tech type.

TAG_DISCOVERED is a catch all for anything non standard and should not really be used.

As you mention an e-money Tag, then this is likely to be a NFC Type 4 Tag using A or B Tech Type and will probably use the [IsoDep](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep) class for communication.

BUT you will need to have the datasheet for the card on what ISO 7816-4 commands it supports, it probably support some of the EMV APDU's. This type of Tag is more complicated to work with and you will have to have detail knowledge of this area to be able to work with this type of Tag and some of the details will be restricted access.